# Как устанавливать программы в ubuntu

Tags: установка, ubuntu

Например, у меня есть скачанный файл `programm.bin`. Двойной клик ничего не даёт, как установить эту программу? Тот же вопрос по файлу `programm.tar.gz`. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правило, дают инструкции для установки программ под линукс. Если таковая отсутствует, подобные файл обычно запускаются из командной строки с правами рута:

```
cd место-где-программа
sudo ./programm.bin
```

.tar.gz - это архив. Чтобы его распаковать, надо использовать либо какой-то графический архиватор (file-roller в GNOME, ark в KDE), либо в коммандной строке написать:

```
tar xvzf Имя-файла
```

Возможно вам понадобится собрать программу из исходников, для этого нужно поочередно ввести команды:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Как правило перед

sudo ./programm.bin

Нужно еще сделать chmod +x ./programm.bin

Comment: Точно. Если требуется

Answer (score 0):

Другой вариант, через **"Центр приложений Ubuntu"**

[image: Центр приложений Ubuntu]

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ok.